# Как можно оптимизировать этот код?

Tags: python, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

```
if message.lower().startswith("!top"):
    sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY messages DESC")  # Возвращает столбцы userid(тип данных TEXT), nick(тип данных TEXT), messages(тип данных INT) с таблицы users
    rows = sql.fetchmany(10)  # Первые 10 записей
    z = []    # Этот массив для добавления сюда nick и messages
    for x in rows:
       z.append(x[1])  # Добавляет в массив nick
       z.append(x[2])  # Добавляет в массив messages(кол-во сообщений пользователя)
    sub_client.send_message(chatId=chatid,
                            message="TOP-10: \n" + "1. " + str(
                                            z[0]) + " " + str(z[1]) + "\n" + "2. " + str(
                                            z[2]) + " " + str(z[3]) + "\n" + "3. " + str(
                                            z[4]) + " " + str(z[5]) + "\n" + "4. " + str(
                                            z[6]) + " " + str(z[7]) + "\n" + "5. " + str(
                                            z[8]) + " " + str(z[9]) + "\n" + "6. " + str(
                                            z[10]) + " " + str(z[11]) + "\n" + "7. " + str(
                                            z[12]) + " " + str(z[13]) + "\n" + "8. " + str(
                                            z[14]) + " " + str(z[15]) + "\n" + "9. " + str(
                                            z[16]) + " " + str(z[17]) + "\n" + "10. " + str(
                                            z[18]) + " " + str(z[19]))  # Отправляет сообщение в чат
```

Так как массив `z` выглядит таким образом `[nick, messages, nick, messages, nick, messages ...]` то обращаясь по индексам `z[0], z[1]` можно вывести сообщение с форматом "Ник кол-во сообщений". Но если нужно будет вывести топ 50, то каждый раз вписывать индексы это довольно муторно, как можно это сделать по другому?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь циклами. Например, циклом for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проще использовать сущность `nick message`, объединяя её в кортеж или свой класс какой-то, чем хранить отдельными элементами, я сделал кортежами, потом в цикле просто формируем сообщение, проходясь по списку кортежей

```
if message.lower().startswith("!top"):
    sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY messages DESC") 
    rows = sql.fetchmany(10) 

    z = []    
    for x in rows:
       z.append((x[1], x[2]))  # Добавляет в z (nick, message)

    full_message = "TOP-10: \n"
    for i, (name, message) in enumerate(z, 1):
       full_message += f'{i}. {name} {message}\n'

    sub_client.send_message(chatId=chatid, message=full_message)
```

Comment: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)` ругается на `for i, nick, message in enumerate(z, 1):`

Comment: @lynx1 да была ошибка, поправил

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо!